# Easy way to cascade binding updates

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

Just hit a snag in my MVVM application that's made me wonder if I'm doing MVVM "right", or if I've missed a trick somewhere. Consider a situation like this on the viewmodel:

```
private _bookings ObservableCollection<Booking>;
public ObservableCollection<Booking> Bookings
{
    get { return _bookings; }
    set
    {
        _bookings = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Bookings");
    }
}

public int Requested
{
    get
    {
        return (int)Bookings.Sum(g => g.Requested);
    }
}

public int Available
{
    get
    {
        return (int)Bookings.Sum(g => g.Volume);
    }
}
```

And then in a datagrid on the view:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Bookings, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding SourceCollection}">
    <!-- various datagrid related gubbins -->
</DataGrid>
<Label BorderThickness="1" Content="{Binding Requested}"></Label>
<Label BorderThickness="1" Content="{Binding Available}"></Label>
```

Now, whenever something in the ViewModel changes the contents of the Bookings collection, the contents of my grid will auto-update which is great.

But the Active and Requested properties which are calculated on the contents of that collection don't auto update, and can't because they're read-only. Even if I made each one two way and raised a changed event for them both (which I'm reluctant to do, because in the real-world version there are a lot of these dependent properties), the code chokes on execution because you can't make a two-way binding to a read-only property.

Is there any straightforward way round this problem, ideally to cascade changes to dependent properties and have them auto-update in the view?

Comment: Don't set your ObservableCollection.  Listen for changes, then fire OnPropertyChanged for all dependent properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [@dellywheel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22791175/632337) mentioned in his answer that you need to cascade property changes if you want controls bound to these properties to get change notification.

However, if you are dealing with small class and can afford property changes, you can **raise `PropertyChanged` event with empty string** so all properties in class will pass on property change notification to UI. That ways you won't have to raise individual property change events for each properties.

```
OnPropertyChanged("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise the OnPropertyChanged after Bookings collection changes (or wherever you need to in your code).

```
private _bookings ObservableCollection<Booking>;
public ObservableCollection<Booking> Bookings
{
    get { return _bookings; }
    set
    {
        _bookings = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Bookings");
        OnPropertyChanged("Requested");
        OnPropertyChanged("Available");        
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a more straightforward approach than this - it's going to be a very long (and ugly) list of properties to update, otherwise.

Comment: Cant think of another way as binding needs to know that property has changed. You could tidy with clean helper methods updating all relevant properties

Comment: Yes, that's the way I've done it. Thanks for clarifying - sometimes it just feels like there should be a cleaner way to do things :)

Comment: I don't think the above is 'dirty'. You could look at a Mediator if you find your self needing to do this across various classes...